# Use maven to extract common package prefix?

Tags: java, maven, package

I am using maven for my Java project analysis. What I need now is, given a target maven project, I would like to use mvn command to get the common Java package prefix in this project. For example, assume the given target maven project has the following packages structure:

```
org.apache.commons.maths3.someone
org.apache.commons.mathse.someone.innerone
org.apache.commons.maths3.anotherone
org.apache.commons.camel.yetanotherone
```

Then the common package prefix should be "org.apache.commons".

I searched through quite a lot of mvn documents but did not find one or two command combination that can do this. Does mvn support this level of analysis or not? If yes, how? Or if no, could you tell me alternative command combination to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Is it? The actual problem is to get common package prefix in a maven project, with the restriction that I can only use mvn command line tools.

Comment: But why? Do you want to relocate classes during packaging?

Comment: That'll be a even more complicated story. To simply put, I need this so that I can restrict my full-program analysis to consider only classes with the prefix common in this project. More specifically, for example, I won't need to consider java.lang.*, sun.com.*, and other lib classes, etc.

Comment: You should edit your question with your real use case and tell about the real thing you want to do, with what you've tried and have so far. This question is very _very_ weird.